# Was trying to solve the Leetcode 78 Print Subsets problem. Why am i getting the output list as like this [[].[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]?

Tags: python, recursion

```
def addsubsets(nums,el,i,n):
    if i==n:                    
        output.append(el)
        return

    el.append(nums[i])
    addsubsets(nums,el,i+1,n)
    el.remove(nums[i])
    addsubsets(nums,el,i+1,n)
        
output=[]
                
nums=[1,2,3]
addsubsets(nums,[],0,len(nums))   
print(output)
```

#I was expecting output list as[[1,2,3],[1,2],[1,3],[1],[2,3],[2],[3],[]]. i am not able to understand why the output list is not getting appended with the list "el". Please help me to understand.!

Problem statement: Given an integer array nums of unique elements, return all possible subsets (the power set).

The solution set must not contain duplicate subsets. Return the solution in any order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are adding a reference of the same list (`el`) to the `output`. And then removing elements from `el`.

Try `output.append(el.copy())`

Comment: ok i understood now. Can you please elaborate what difference will el.copy() make?

Comment: When you do `output.append(el)` you always add the reference of the same list. And then you do `el.remove(nums[i])` which removes the value from that list. At the end, the `el` will be empty, so all your references in `output` will reference the same empty list. But when you use `.copy()` it creates a copy of the `el` at the moment when it has needed values. So in the end `output` will store references to different lists that are not cleaned with `el.remove(nums[i])`.